# Changing the value of one dropdown is changing the value of the other

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem when I change the value of one dropdown on `ng-change`. It will changes the other dropdown value also even both dropdown ids are different.
[image]

anyone knows why its happening?

Below is my code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="Billable{{$index}}" ng-init="invoice.source_item=''" ng-model="invoice.source_item" ng-change="BillableItemDetails(invoice.source_item,$index)">
    <option class="ng-binding" value="">Select Billable Item...</option>
    <option class="ng-binding" ng-repeat="BillableItem in BilableItemsList" value="{{BillableItem.id}}">{{BillableItem.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, this is b'cos your all dropdown hav same `ng-model`, so when you change value of any dropdown its reflect to all dropdown by 'ng-model' - 2-way-binding.

Comment: thanks @gauravbhavsar for your reply so is there any solution?

Comment: Yes, Create plunk with dummy data or provide dummy data in question so I am able to create plunkr for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different `ng-model` variable with different dropdown

Here is [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/AxLli7KFu2jKaSKHTU0h?p=preview)

**HTML**

```
<select ng-model="dd1_Value" ng-change="changedd(ddValue.key)">
  <option ng-repeat="d in dd track by d.id">{{d.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>DropDown 1 : {{dd1_Value}}</p>


<select ng-model="dd2_Value">
  <option ng-repeat="d in dd track by d.id">{{d.name}}</option>
</select> 

<p>DropDown 2 : {{dd2_Value}}</p>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

$scope.dd = [
    {id:1,name:'a'},
    {id:2,name:'b'},
    {id:3,name:'c'},
    {id:4,name:'d'},
    {id:5,name:'e'},
    {id:6,name:'f'}
]

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `ng-model="invoice.source_item"` to a unique scope variable for each DropDown.

Comment: how we can do. any demo?

Comment: Just change the xxxxx  in ng-model="xxxxx" to a unique variable name.